# Apache Camel - process in XML DSL using #class not working

Tags: apache-camel, apache-camel-3

I am trying to build a camel standalone app for a one-time activity - using `camel-main`. I have successfully built XML DSL for basic routing.

Now as part of the process, I want to invoke a custom java processor.

As per https://camel.apache.org/manual/processor.html#_referring_to_beans_using_class_syntax, it indicates that this should be possible using #class convention.

I added following to my route file:

It does not seem to work for me. Are there any pre-requisites for this?
Error returned is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> process[ref:#class:org.myorg.camel.MyProcessor] <<< in route: Route(route1)[From[timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period=60000] ... because of No bean could be found in the registry for: #class:org.myorg.camel.MyProcessor of type: org.apache.camel.Processor
        at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.doCreateRoute(RouteReifier.java:240)
```

Here is my sample code:
https://github.com/chiragsanghavi/camel-experiments/blob/main/processor

Route:

```
<route>
     <from uri="timer://foo?fixedRate=true&amp;period=60000"/>
    <setBody>
        <simple>Hello</simple>
    </setBody>
    <process ref="#class:org.myorg.camel.MyProcessor"/>
    <to uri="log:hello"/>
</route>
```

Processor

```
package org.myorg.camel;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;


import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
public class MyProcessor implements Processor {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyProcessor.class);
    public MyProcessor()
    {

    }
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange)  {
        logger.trace("Processing for "+exchange.getExchangeId());

        String payload = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        // do something with the payload and/or exchange here
        exchange.getIn().setBody(payload+"X");
        exchange.getIn().setHeader("NewHeader","SampleValue");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a instance of `com.mypackage.myclass.MyCustomProcessor` in your XML DSL? For my understanding Camel adds beans defined in beans.xml or Blueprint.xml to the registry which you can then refer to either by ID or Type.

Comment: without using camel-spring-main not sure how to add beans.xml; is there any pointers? I will explore blueprint.xml.

Comment: **beans.xml** is for spring, **blueprint xml** is for OSGi/Karaf. If you're writing camel routes with XML DSL you're likely using one or the other already.  It's basically the xml file where you've defined the camel context and routes using XML DSL.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Update: This was confirmed as not working and a fix has been worked on by Claus for 3.15.x, can't wait to see it released.